# Java and Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String cmd)

Tags: java, linux, terminal, openssl

i'm trying to write a program ,that have toexecute the same code in linux terminal:

```
openssl req -passout pass:abc -subj /C=US/ST=IL/L=Chicago/O=IBM          Corporation/OU=IBM Software Group/CN=John Smith/emailAddress=smith@abc.ibm.com -new > johnsmith.cert.csr
```

In the terminal it works fine, but in Java it didn't.
I try something like this, but without result.

```
String[] cmd = { "openssl", "req -passout pass:abc -subj", "/C=US/ST=IL/L=Chicago/O=IBM          Corporation/OU=IBM Software Group/CN=John Smith/emailAddress=smith@abc.ibm.com", "-new > johnsmith.cert.csr" };
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Can you explain me, what i miss.Thanks in advance.
Best wishes Andrey

Comment: Have you tried: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("openssl req -passout pass:abc -subj /C=US/ST=IL/L=Chicago/O=IBM          Corporation/OU=IBM Software Group/CN=John Smith/emailAddress=smith@abc.ibm.com -new > johnsmith.cert.csr");`?

Comment: Did you see any error?  If yes, what was the error message?

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the fact that stream redirection `>` is a functionality of shell that does not exist here.

You can either prepend your command with `/bin/sh -c` or redirect output using java:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
InputStream in = proc.setOutputStream();
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("johnsmith.cert.csr");
int b;
while( (b = in.read()) != -1) {
   out.write(b);
}
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Now you can remove `"> johnsmith.cert.csr"` from your command line. I personally like this solution more.

Comment: Thank you.I found that i have syntacsys error in command, but you are right for the file.Thank you